# Javascript promises referencing external variable

Tags: javascript, angularjs, promise, protractor

I'm trying to understand how promises works in js. I have the following protractor test:

```
fieldConstraintsList.forEach(function(constrains){

     // WARNING... or not??
     var input = element(by.model(constrains.model)); //Getting input element

     input.getAttribute('value').then(function(initialValue){

           // Do validation stuff....

           //WARNING... or not??
           input.clear();//Restore initial value
      });
});
```

This receive a list of constraints to apply to a form with a model that identify each input. As you can see, a promise is executed inside the loop so, as long as there is a reference to the `input` variable that is declared outside of the promise, I expect a different behavior (see edit section later).

Some one can gives me some tips or reference??

Thanks in advance.

EDITED

I was expecting a behavior like this: supposing `constrains` has length 2, 2 elements are created: `input = A` and `input = B`, and, again, 2 promises are created `promise(A)` and `promise(B)`. As long as the promises are not immediately resolved (or yes???) when promise(A) is resolved then `input = B` and B should be the one to be clear and not A.

In short this is what I have been expecting: `input = A` => `input = B` => `promise(A)` =>  `promise(B)`

The actual behavior of the applications that is annoying me is: `input = A` => `promise(A)` => `input = B` => `promise(B)`.

Comment: So you are asking why it is working, instead of.. why something is not working? Well, that's new :D

Comment: I don't understand what _"referencing external variable"_ has to do with the fact that you use a promise. And what _"strange behavior"_ did you expect?

Comment: This is called __closures__ and is a fundamental property of some languages including JavaScript. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/111102/how-do-javascript-closures-work